# Jmeter plugin for Teamcity - Teamcity shows all Jmeter tests failed but in the log they all passed

Tags: automation, jmeter, teamcity

I added the Jmeter plugin for Teamcity according to : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration

After running the tests, Teamcity reports: "Tests failed: 13, passed: 0", but all the tests passed according to the log  :"Generate Summary Results =     13 in 00:00:03 =    4.4/s Avg:   205 Min:    23 Max:  1377 **Err:     0 (0.00%)**".

How can I configure Teamcity to show the correct results?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you changed user.properties?

Comment: Yes, I changed the properties:
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @TravisSmith, Unfortunately no, I'm currently checking the results manually

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and found a solution after reading these channels:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935009/5210267 and 
https://github.com/jtorgan/jmeter_plugin/issues/24#issuecomment-421016226

The plugin expects to have "success" column in some exact position or exact order in the output file. For me it worked when "success" was the 4th column (more info in the articles I mentioned above).

You can achieve it by turning off columns in the report file, for example:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
```

But when I reached working configurations, generation of html report with `-e -o Report` command stopped working.

So, I just went to "Build Features" settings and turned off the "assertions" checkbox and added my own Build Failure conditions.